# Is there a way to handle the sent of thousand messages in Rabbitmq without losting any message

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I am working on a **spring boot** application that receives messages from an other application through **rabbitmq**  and do some tasks after that it sent these messages in an other queue of **rabbitmq**, every thing is good but some times the application don't sent one or two messages in the **queue**, to handle this problem I used **Synchronized** but now I have an issue of performance. I am using **rabbitmq 2.1.8** and **spring boot 2.1.8**

Answer (score 1):

With current versions (since 2.0) there are a couple of different ways to wait for publisher confirmations.

See [the documentation "Publishing is Asynchronous — How to Detect Successes and Failures"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#publishing-is-async)